# Use loop function in R to calculate sedimentation rate?

Tags: r

I've got some river sedimentation data. Each river consisted 2 sites with 2-3 sedimentation plates.Experiment was conducted for 10 years and sediment depth (mm) of deposited sediment on each plate was measured in 1-3 years interval. I am wondering is it possible to use R loop to calculate sedimentation rate for each site for each river? sample data were attached.

```html
River Site Plate Year "Sedement 
depth(mm)"
ES1 SiteA Plate 1 2009 220
ES1 SiteA Plate 1 2011 207
ES1 SiteA Plate 1 2012 203
ES1 SiteA Plate 1 2013 210
ES1 SiteA Plate 1 2015 211.7
ES1 SiteA Plate 1 2016 218
ES1 SiteA Plate 1 2018 207
ES1 SiteA Plate 1 2019 219.7
ES1 SiteA Plate 2 2009 183
ES1 SiteA Plate 2 2011 173
ES1 SiteA Plate 2 2012 180
ES1 SiteA Plate 2 2013 180
ES1 SiteA Plate 2 2015 184
ES1 SiteA Plate 2 2016 185
ES1 SiteA Plate 2 2018 178
ES1 SiteA Plate 2 2019 185.3
ES2 SiteB Plate 1 2009 191
ES2 SiteB Plate 1 2011 190
ES2 SiteB Plate 1 2012 190
ES2 SiteB Plate 1 2013 191
ES2 SiteB Plate 1 2015 192.3
ES2 SiteB Plate 1 2016 195
ES2 SiteB Plate 1 2018 186
ES2 SiteB Plate 1 2019 190.3
ES2 SiteB Plate 2 2009 212
ES2 SiteB Plate 2 2011 214
ES2 SiteB Plate 2 2012 205
ES2 SiteB Plate 2 2013 203
ES2 SiteB Plate 2 2015 190.7
ES2 SiteB Plate 2 2016 197
ES2 SiteB Plate 2 2018 188
ES2 SiteB Plate 2 2019 191.3
```

Sedimentation rate for each site can be calculated as follow;

E.g. ES1,SiteA, Year 2015 = Plate 1 (211.7-210)/2(year diff)
                            Plate 2 (184-180)/2

```
  Sedimentation rate for 2015 = avg [Plate 1 (211.7-210)/2(year diff)+ Plate 2 (184-180)/2]
```

Comment: please post input data _as text_

Comment: It's a good idea to include your data in a copy-and-pasteable format, such as the output from `dput`, and also to include an explicit statement of your desired output. It's also helpful if you include the code you've tried so far and an explanation of why it doesn't work (e.g., what errors you encountered). `diff` would be useful here (check out `?diff`) and, rather than using a loop, try using `group_by` in `dplyr` or `by` in `data.table` and group by plate and site before doing the calculation.

Comment: Thanks for let me know. I just added my data as text.

Comment: Thanks Lyngbakr, I'll try with dplyr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have uploaded the data into R. Then, you could do `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
#create the year diff column, the rate diff column and the rate diff column
table <- table %>%
   group_by(River, Site, Plate) %>%
   mutate(Year_diff = Year - lag(Year),
          sediment_depth_diff = Sedement_depth_mm - lag(Sedement_depth_mm),
          sediment_depth_diff_per_year = sediment_depth_diff/Year_diff)

#create new table with average rate per river, site, year
table_summary <- table %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(River, Site, Year) %>%
    summarise(avg_rate = mean(sediment_depth_diff_per_year))
```

Comment: Thanks Guilherme